# Need Help Formulating a Pyomo Linear Programme - Scheduling Problem

Tags: python, constraints, linear-programming, solver, pyomo

I have a dataset the contains information about a number of lessons in multiple syllabus', the classrooms that will be used in those syllabus' and how long the classroom will be used for (e.g. if a lesson is an hour, the classroom will be used for an hour). An example of each dataset are below (the datasets are quite long so i have only provided the head of each):

syllabus_df:

```
    +------------+----------+-----+----------+-------------+
    |syllabus_id |lesson_id |day  |classroom |lesson_length|
    +------------+----------+-----+----------+-------------+
    |s101        |l1        |day1 |cr1       |1            |
    |s101        |l2        |day1 |cr2       |2            |
    |s101        |l3        |day2 |cr1       |2            |
    |s102        |l4        |day1 |cr3       |4            |
    |s102        |l5        |day2 |cr4       |2            |
    +-----------------------+-----+----------+-------------+


classroom_df:
    +-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
    |session_id |classroom_id |date       |availability |
    +-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
    |ses1       |cr1          |01/01/2024 |8            |
    |ses2       |cr1          |01/02/2024 |9            |
    |ses3       |cr1          |01/03/2024 |8            |
    |ses4       |cr1          |01/04/2024 |7            |
    |ses5       |cr1          |01/05/2024 |9            |
    |ses6       |cr1          |01/06/2024 |7            |
    |ses7       |cr1          |01/07/2024 |7            |
    +-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
```

Where the classroom_df dataframe shows the availability of each classroom for each date of the year and a 'session' is a unique id for 'classroom + date'

So I want the LP to create a schedule for the year using this information.

The objective function would be to maximise number of syllabus' running during each day.

I'm struggling to think of how to programme the following constraints:

1. ensure that the sum of lesson_length < availability of the classroom for each day
2. all lessons in the same syllabus should be run on consecutive days (hence the 'days' column; day1, day2, day3, etc.). Some Classrooms are not available on weekends so i will accept 'the next available day' as a viable solution with a gap of a few days in the syllabus

This is the code i have so far, based on [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/schedule-optimisation-using-linear-programming-in-python-9b3e1bc241e1) example:

```
import pyomo.environ as pe
import pyomo
import pandas as pd

model = pe.ConcreteModel

# list of lesson id's
model.LESSONS = pe.Set(initialize=list(syllabus_df.lesson_id))
# list of syllabus id's
model.SYLLABUSES = pe.Set(initialize=list(syllabus_df.syllabus_id.unique()))
# list of session id's
model.SESSIONS = pe.Set(initialize=list(classroom_df.session_id))
# list of classroom id's
model.CLASSROOMS = pe.Set(initialize=list(classroom_df. classroom_id.unique()))
# list of all possible lesson-session combinations
model.SCHEDULE_LESSONS = pe.Set(initialize=model.LESSONS * model.SESSIONS, dimen=2)
# the lesson length for each lesson
model.LESSON_LENGTH = pe.Param(model.LESSONS, initialize=self._generate_lesson_durations())
# the availability of each session
model.SESSION_AVAILABILITY = pe.Param(model.SESSIONS, initialize=self._generate_session_availability)
# the available dates for each session
model.SESSION_DATES = pe.Param(model.SESSIONS, initialize=self._get_session_dates())

num_lessons = self.syllabus_df.shape[0]

# DECISION VARIABLES
model.SESSION_ASSIGNED = pe.Var(model.SCHEDULE_LESSONS, domain=pe.Binary)
model.LESSONS_IN_SESSION = pe.Var(model.SESSIONS, bounds=(0, num_lessons), within=pe.PositiveReals)

# OBJECTIVE
def objective_function(model):
    return pe.summation(model.LESSONS_IN_SESSION)
model.OBJECTIVE = pe.Objective(rule=objective_function, sense=pe.maximize)

# CONSTRAINTS
# need help here and also with the solver
```

thanks in advance to those who help, i really appreciate it!

Comment: This is a pretty big ask (somebody to write your whole project) and not really focused.  I'd recommend you put a LOT more work into the problem first.  Perhaps try to get a lesser problem working like try to pair lessons to to classrooms within some fixed capacity.  Then expand to lessons & classrooms to days, etc.  There is quite a bit of nuance (and learning) that you will discover that is not in the problem description.

Comment: Sure, but it's all related.  If you don't have "the math" written out or at least some working lesser model to build on, then building a couple of the key constraints involves re-working the variables and perhaps the objective, etc..  My point is, if you have an exemplar working or kinda working -- even if it doesn't do everything, that is an easier ask.  The solution below is certainly on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Pyomo programming but hope this formulation will help:
Parameters:
Lesson duration: `d[l,c]`  where `s=`syllabus, `l=` lesson, `c=`classroom
Availability:  `a[c,d]` where `d=` date
Sets (Tuples/dataFrames) `(S,L)`

Variables
Binary  `x[l,c,d], y[s,d]`

Constraints
Loop  over 'c,d`:

`sum(d[l,c]*x[l,c,d] over l) <= a[c,d]` : Takes care of your first constraint

Loop over `s`:
`N = |s|`
`N*y[s,d] - sum(y[s,k] over k from 1 to d-1) <= N*y[s,d+1]` loop over d, except last date:
Or
`N*y[s,d-1] - sum(y[s,k] over k from 1 to d-2) <= N*y[s,d]` loop over date except first date:
Here your `d =` available dates & `N =` cardinality of syllabus(number of lessons in syllabus `s`)

`y[s,d] <=sum(sum(x[l,c,d] over c) over l in s) <= Ny[s,d]`

`sum(y[s,d] over d) = N`

Loop over `l` in `s`:
`sum(sum(x[l,c,d] over c) over d) <=1` 
Above constraints ensures consecutive allocation of classrooms and dates for lessons in a syllabus.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I’ll see if I can work it into the promo modelling :)

Comment: Thanks, made a couple of more edits to make constraints tighter.

Comment: Hey, just trying to model it now. I have a few questions. 
1) with variable notation such as d[l, c] is this variable a Python dictionary with lesson duration as key and a tuple of the respective lesson and classroom as the value?
2) What is the variable K that you introduced?  Is this the incrementing value for looping over each day in the syllabus?
3) When you say “over k” or “over l”, am I dividing by the number of lessons or days? 

Thanks again for your help so far!

Comment: D[l,c] is duration with l,c as dict key or multi-index if using data frame. K is temporary variable to loop over day 1 to day-1 when looping for days. That constraint, you will need to loop over dates. Basically I am trying to allocate consecutive dates to a syllabus. The constraint is trying this: before allocating a day to a syllabus ensure the previous date is assigned and check if all lessons in the syllabus,s  are not done. I have another alternative constraint under Or. Either should work.